# SSIS: Passing record set into a Stored Proc

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, parameters, ssis

I'm using SSIS with SQL Server 2005, I want to pass a data set as a parameter into a sproc. Inside the sproc, I have to process the records and insert into some destination table.
Is there a direct way to do it in SSIS(passing data set as a parameter part)?
Or do I've to convert the table records into XML and then pass it as parameters..

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to pass the entire data set into a stored proc (other than by converting to xml).

The alternative is to move your logic from your stored proc and set SSIS up to manage the destination logic.